# Retornar list para ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

Eu tenho esta função para carregar alguns dados, porém surgiu a necessidade de carregar uma `list` e incluir em uma `table` a função ficou desta forma:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CarregaProduto(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = db.Produtos.Where(r => r.Codigo == id).Single();
            var produtoempresa = db.ProdutosEmpresas.Include(a => a.EmpresaProduto).Where(a => a.ProdutoEmpresa.Codigo == id).ToList();
            return Json(new
            {
                nomeProduto = item.nome,
                precoUnitario = item.PrecoCusto,
                id = item.Id,
                tipo = item.TipoProduto,
                Resultado = item.Codigo,
                listaEstoque = produtoempresa,
            });

        }
        catch { return Json(new { Resultado = 0 }); }
    }
```

A `produtoempresa` retorna a `list`, porém como posso mandar os dados e carregá-los, via `HTML` ?

Aqui é a função:

```
function CarregaProduto(id) {
    var url = "/PedidoVenda/CarregaProduto";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , data: { id: id }
        , type: "POST"
        , datatype: "html"
        , success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data.resultado);
            if (data.resultado != 0) {
                $("#descricaoproduto").html(data.nomeProduto);
                var preco = ((data.precoUnitario));
                $("#precocusto").val(parseFloat(preco).toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
                $("#produtoid").val(data.id);
                $("#idproduto").val(data.resultado);
                $("#tipo").val(data.tipo);
            }
            else {
                $("#descricaoproduto").html("Não encontrado, pesquise novamente.");
                $("#precocusto").val("");
                $("#idproduto").val("");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Como posso carregar a lista nesta função `CarregaProduto` ?
Consegui enviar, coloquei um `console.log(data.listaEstoque);` ele esta retornando os dados corretamente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei adicionar em uma div, desta forma:

```
 var dvItems = $("#dvItems");
                dvItems.empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    var $tr = $('<li>').append(data.listaEstoque).appendTo(dvItems);
                });
```

Porém também não funciona, como carregar os dados ?

Comment: Ta, não entendi sua duvida, mas primeiro você deveria estar retornando um JsonResult e não um ActionResult

Comment: No html vc pode receber esses dados via ajax e le-los

Comment: @MarcosBrinner eu preciso carregar uma `table`, eu estou utilizando MVC CORE

Comment: @MarcosBrinner eu preciso mandar além destes dados que estão no return Json, preciso retornar agora também `list`

Comment: @MarcosBrinner editei a pergunta, agora acho que ficou mais clara, preciso apenas carregar os dados em html, tentei carregar em uma div, porém não deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem sua dúvida. Mas, vamos lá:

- Retorne um JsonResult;
- Percorra a produtoempresa e adicione na lista que irá retornar no JSON;

Abaixo foi uma solução que utilizei aqui na empresa para usar o GoogleChart retornando um Json:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public JsonResult Filtro(string dataInicio, string dataFinal, int? searchContrato)
    {
        try
        {

            int qtdeAjuda = QuantidadeAjuda(dataInicio, dataFinal, searchContrato);

            List<Analytics> g = new List<Analytics>()
            {  
                new Analytics(13, "Ajuda" + "(" + qtdeAjuda + ")", qtdeAjuda ),

            };

            return Json(new { JSONList = g }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                
        }            
    }
```

Veja se isso pode te ajudar em relação sua dúvida. Abaixo apenas um exemplo de retorno para te dar um norte na resolução do seu problema.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/GetDados",
        success: function (dados) {
            $(dados).each(function (i) {
                document.writeln("<p>Nome: " + dados[i].Nome + " | URL: " + dados[i].URL + "</p>")
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Por utilizar `asp.net core` eu não tenho a opção de utilizar `JsonRequestBehavior` no caso sua solução não funciona para mim.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, preciso apenas passar os dados para o html, da forma que eu estou fazendo não está dando certo.